# python 3.5 robobrowser, fill input with one value at a time

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrap a webpage after entering input value using python 3.5 and robobrowser. The problem I am facing is: While trying to input each value at a time in the input.

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLDistrict" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLDistrict\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DDLDistrict">
    <option value="Select District">Select District</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="8">Agra</option>
    <option value="9">A</option>
    <option value="29">B</option>
    <option value="70">C Nagar</option>
    <option value="72">D</option>
    <option value="58">Y</option>
    <option value="40">Z</option>
</select>
```

Part of my Python code is:

```
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

# Browse to Genius
browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser.open('http://164.100.180.82/ceouptemp/RollPDF.aspx')
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
form = browser.get_form(name='ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLDistrict')
```

Comment: and where is rest of code - more important part of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to double-check, make sure you've actually found the form, but printing the form. The code that follows assumes you have an interactive Python session going with the code you posted above.

```
>>> print(form)
```

If you get some a value that begin with, `<RoboForm __`, then you're in business. If you get `None`, then you haven't actually selected the form and you should try the following to figure where the form is,

```
>>> browser.get_forms()
```

Once you have found the form that includes the select list assigned it the variable name `form`, you can change the value of the form to some values (such as '29' as follows):

```
>>> form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLDistrict'].value = '29'
```

If you want a list of all the options, you can do:

```
>>> form['ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLDistrict'].options
```

Happy scrapping!

Check out the RoboBrowser docs for more information (note the example on checkboxes works just like selects): https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser